# Проверка checkbox на check

Tags: jquery, javascript

Я хочу выполнить проверку при подтверждении формы. Но сразу происходит подтверждение! Проверка чекбокса выполняется.

Да и один момент если галка не установлена, то происходит вызов alert с сообщением и происходит submit, чего собственно делать не надо. Вот [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/nDCBE/) накидал код.

```
<form method="POST" id="target">
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" id="agree" checked><b> <span style="font-size: 11px;">Я даю согласие на обработку данных
    <input type="submit" value="отправить" name="fizsend" id="subButton"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $('#subButton').on('click', function(){     
        if($("#agree").attr("checked") == 'checked') {  
            $('#target').submit(function(){});
        } else {
            window.alert('Дайте свое согласие на обработку данных!');
            $("#agree").css('border', '1px solid red');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Функция-обработчик onclick должна возвращать true или false, в зависимости от состояния чекбокса, например, так:

```
function(){     
    if($("#agree").attr("checked") != 'checked') { 
        window.alert('Дайте свое согласие на обработку данных!');
        $("#agree").css('border', '1px solid red');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

EDIT:
Начиная с jQuery 1.9 метод .attr(..) не поддерживается. Вместо него нужно использовать .prop(...), в вашем случае - с теми же параметрами.

Comment: Благодарю, коллега! Все работает успешно :)

Comment: Я бы ещё проверку на check сделал с помощью jQuery-селекторов:

     $("#agree").is(":not(:checked)")

Comment: По умолчанию **снимите** галочку. Пользователь должен **явно** дать согласие на обработку своих данных установкой галочки. А если это согласие стоит по умолчанию, его можно вообще не делать. Просто написать что "заполняя форму вы соглашаетесь с ...."


А вообще то такие обработки лучше делать в событии `onsubmit` самой формы, поскольку sumbit может быть инициирован не только кликом мышкой, но и, например, нажатием Enter.

Comment: Спасибо всем, принял во внимание все ваши рекомендации!

Comment: jquery attr зло

Comment: Для получения/установки свойств типа checked, selected, disabled следует использовать метод prop: http://api.jquery.com/prop/.

Comment: @ArtemKelpe, по поводу [вашей правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/160963). Не могу найти информацию о том, что метод не поддерживается. Вот тут лишь говорится об удалении недокументированной сигнатуры https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-attr

Answer (score 61):

`$("#agree").prop('checked')` возвращает `true/false`

Comment: Этот вариант правильный.

Comment: тут все правильные, этот более красивый, и не надо проверять на конкретное значение. Плюс возвращает BOOL, что удобно... Так что да, имхо лучший метод из предложенных.

Answer (score 18):

JQuery проверка

```
$("#agree").is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 6):

Вариант без JS ( required+CSS )

```html
<style>
  form:invalid input[type="submit"] {
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
</style>

<form method="POST" id="target">
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" id="agree" required><b> <span style="font-size: 11px;">Я даю согласие на обработку данных
    <input type="submit" value="отправить" name="fizsend" id="subButton"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой вариант будет самым универсальным, подойдет для всех версий Jquery:

```
if($("#agree").is(":checked")) {  
    $('#target').submit(function(){});
}
```

Comment: Не уверен, что понимаю разницу между вашим ответом и ответом от `des1roer`

Comment: Ответил просто на вопрос, который знал. Рейтинг нужно было поднять, чтобы голосовать)
Ответ же правильный, сам его использую)

Comment: Тоже правильно :)

Answer (score 1):

вот еще один способ

```
<form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return checkConfirm()">
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" id="agree" checked><b> <span style="font-size: 11px;"> Я даю согласие на обработку данных
<input type="submit" value="отправить" name="fizsend" id="subButton"/>
</form>




<script>

function checkConfirm() {

    if($("#agree").is(":checked")) {
        return true;
    }
      window.alert('Вы не дали свое согласие!');
    return false;

}
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Смысл использовать jquery только для проверки на чекед?  
2. Про onsubmit атрибут я вообще умолчу  
3. Ну и алерт в 2018 о_О

Comment: 1. алерт только для того, чтобы программист сам решил, что там будет, это простой пример 
2. а что не так с onsubmit-ом, объясни
3. и кто сказал что только для проверки подключается jquery, тут же тема про js и jquery, и если человек задал вопрос тут, то логично предположить что у него jquery уже подключен

Comment: @Air вы действительно считаете, что этот пост должен быть быть комментарием? К какому именно вопросу или ответу?

Comment: @PashaPash, не так не считаю, это просто невнимательность, у меня в 2х - 3х вкладках были вопросы другие открыты во время проверки, я просто не тот ответ рекомендовал на удаление...