# Не удается проверить выбран ли checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть форма с **checkbox**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="calcWater_caisson" name="adapter" value="Yes" />
```

Хочу чтоб результат появился без обновления страницы:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "1.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      data: {
        adapter: document.getElementById('calcWater_caisson').value
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $("#contentST").html(response);
       }
        });
      });
    });
```

Файл где обрабатывет данные формы и выводит результат:

```
if($_POST['adapter'] == 'Yes') {
    $sum3 = "выбран";
}else{
    $sum3 = "отмена";
}
```

Во всех случаях выводит "Выбран"
В чем проблема? Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Дубликат, думаю, этого вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/154275/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-checkbox-%D0%BD%D0%B0-check

Comment: @Visman как это можно сделать в моем коде?

Comment: `if (document.getElementById('calcWater_caisson').checked)` то `data : {adapter : 'Yes'}` или `data : {adapter : document.getElementById('calcWater_caisson').value}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы передаете в пост значение чекбокса, не учитывая его состояние.

Соответственно, вам надо его (состояние) проверить. И исходя из этого отправить нужные данные.
Например

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('calcWater_caisson');

$.ajax({

  url: "1.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  data: {
    adapter: checkbox.checked ? checkbox.value : ''
  },
  success: function(response) {
    $("#contentST").html(response);
   }
});
```

полный код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link").click(function() {   
        var checkbox = document.getElementById('calcWater_caisson');

        $.ajax({   
            url: "1.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {
                adapter: checkbox.checked ? checkbox.value : ''
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $("#contentST").html(response);
            }
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: Вообще не риагирует на форму теперь ... нужно куда то добавить id поля - calcWater_caisson наверное. я в ajax не силен

Comment: ну так перед вызовом аякс надо. поправил. чтобы вы видели весь свой код полностью

Comment: При помощи jQuery можно проверить свойство так: `$("#calcWater_caisson").prop("checked")`

Comment: или даже так `$("#calcWater_caisson").is(':checked')`

Answer (score 4):

Вы передаете в `1.php` не выбран ли чекбокс. Нет, вы передаете его значение (`value`), а оно-то присутствует вне зависимости от состояния. Оно всегда там... Так что Ваш код правильно вам говорит :)

Я бы сделал вот так:

```
data: {
    adapter: ($('#calcWater_caisson').is(":checked")?'Yes':'No')
},
```

Comment: тот же результат

Comment: @cyadvert, да, `$('#calcWater_caisson:checked')` в обоих случаях возвращает объект, отсюда и `Yes` всегда.

Comment: @Visman - спасибо. исправлено

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#calcWater_caisson').prop('checked') // true|false
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще один вариант с использованием jQuery.

Строку

```
adapter: document.getElementById('calcWater_caisson').value
```

следует заменить на

```
adapter: $('#calcWater_caisson:checked').val() || ''
```

Передает значение `value` или пустую строку.