# Разрешить отправить форму только при включенном checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Есть форма с checkbox. Как сделать проверку, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку отправки формы проверялось, нажат ли checkbox? Я делаю так, но он всегда запрещает отправку:
js:

```
if (($(th).find("#agree_private")).prop("checked") != "checked") {
        alert("Дайте согласие на обработку данных")
} else {
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        })...   
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="form_os" id="form_os_phone" method="post" class="b-form">
  <input onchange="check_form(this.form); return false;" name="fio" id="fio" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя *" required>
  <input onchange="check_form(this.form); return false;" name="phone" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Телефон *" pattern='^[-0-9 ()+]+$' required>
  <textarea onchange="check_form(this.form); return false;" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Ваше сообщение *" required></textarea>
  <input onchange="check_form(this.form); return false;" name="agree_private" id="agree_private" value="1" class="b-nice-checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
  <label for="agree_private">я согласен на обработку персональных данных</label></div>ass="qaptcha"></div>
  <input name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно прицепиться к событию `submit` и при нежелании отправлять форму возвращать `false`, например так :

```js
function func(that) {
  var a = that.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  return !!a;
};
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return func(this);">
  <input type="checkbox" value="atata" />
  <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

А если попробовать false/true возвращать в функции? 
как например тут написано - [Проверка checkbox на check](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/154275/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-checkbox-%D0%BD%D0%B0-check)

Answer (score 0):

Также  как временное решение можно сделать checkbox'у атрибут required, если кому некогда настраивать submit.